# batch file from scheduled task returns code 2147942401

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a job to run a batch file with Windows 10 Task Scheduler, but it results in return code *2147942401*.

The batch file is on remote location so I am giving the absolute path
"`\\\server1\file transfers\data files\inbound\abc\csv\excel-to-csv.bat`"

[image]

[image]

If I run the batch script with command prompt then it work fine. Properties - General Actions - Edit Action

The batch script is to convert excel to file to csv.

Content of the script is:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("\\server1\file transfers\Data Files\Inbound\abc\CSV\*.xlsx" ) DO to-csv.vbs  "\\server1\file transfers\Data Files\Inbound\abc\*.xlsx" "%%~ni.csv"
Its calling another VB script which is to-cvs.vbs
```

If i make changes in Action tab as mention by @Steinspecht(Task scheduler- task completed “successfully” with exit code 0x8007001) then also i am getting the code  2147942401
[Not sure whether Add a arguments is written correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhHv8.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and [this_solution](https://agilemusings.blogspot.com/2016/04/task-scheduler-with-non-zero-return-code.html) helped me.
The thing is to separate script name from its path, by using the "Start in" parameter. Just tooo simple.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too and what finally resolved it was changing one of the general settings from "Run whether user is logged on or not" to "Run only when user is logged on".

Even if my computer is locked, it will run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).